# AES encryption using Java

Tags: java, security, aes

I have been using AES encryption to authentic users. But recently faced an issue when an user upgraded his product and when he tried to login with his credentials, below error message thrown to jboss:

```
11:17:02,907 INFO  [stdout] (ajp-/0.0.0.0:9009-1) Caused by: aesdpapi.AesDataProtectionAPIException: A native error occured in function 'UnprotectData'.  Error 87 : The parameter is incorrect.

11:17:02,907 INFO  [stdout] (ajp-/0.0.0.0:9009-1) 

11:17:02,907 INFO  [stdout] (ajp-/0.0.0.0:9009-1)   at aesdpapi.AesDataProtectionAPI.unprotectDataNative(Native Method)

11:17:02,907 INFO  [stdout] (ajp-/0.0.0.0:9009-1)   at aesdpapi.AesDataProtectionAPI.unprotectData(AesDataProtectionAPI.java:348)

11:17:02,907 INFO  [stdout] (ajp-/0.0.0.0:9009-1)   at com.gehcit.cp.security.bo.impl.LDAPAuthenticationModel.decryptLdapPasswordUsingAES(LDAPAuthenticationModel.java:348)

11:17:02,907 INFO  [stdout] (ajp-/0.0.0.0:9009-1)   at com.gehcit.cp.security.bo.impl.LDAPAuthenticationModel.getRSAPasswordFromAES(LDAPAuthenticationModel.java:326)

11:17:02,907 INFO  [stdout] (ajp-/0.0.0.0:9009-1)   at com.gehcit.cp.security.bo.impl.LDAPAuthenticationModel.decryptLdapPassword(LDAPAuthenticationModel.java:312)

11:17:02,923 INFO  [stdout] (ajp-/0.0.0.0:9009-1)   at com.gehcit.cp.security.bo.impl.LDAPAuthenticationModel.loadLDAPAttributes(LDAPAuthenticationModel.java:229)

11:17:02,923 INFO  [stdout] (ajp-/0.0.0.0:9009-1)   at com.gehcit.cp.security.bo.impl.LDAPAuthenticationModel.<init>(LDAPAuthenticationModel.java:186)

11:17:02,923 INFO  [stdout] (ajp-/0.0.0.0:9009-1)   at com.gehcit.cp.security.bo.impl.AuthenticationModelFactoryImpl.createInstance_aroundBody0(AuthenticationModelFactoryImpl.java:49)

11:17:02,923 INFO  [stdout] (ajp-/0.0.0.0:9009-1)   at com.gehcit.cp.security.bo.impl.AuthenticationModelFactoryImpl$AjcClosure1.run(AuthenticationModelFactoryImpl.java:1)

11:17:02,923 INFO  [stdout] (ajp-/0.0.0.0:9009-1)   at org.aspectj.runtime.reflect.JoinPointImpl.proceed(JoinPointImpl.java:149)

11:17:02,923 INFO  [stdout] (ajp-/0.0.0.0:9009-1)   at com.gehcit.cp.aop.monitor.MonitoredClassAspect.run(MonitoredClassAspect.java:53)
```

**aesdpapi** is my custome library to store AES related files. I need to know why am I getting this exception, what can be the probable cause of this exception.

I suspect that the new version is using the new key to decrypt the user password, which was encrypted with old key before the upgrading the product. After the upgrade a new key has got generated, which is unable to decrypt the password which was encrypted by old key.

Comment: Did you upgrade the library?

Comment: No. I haven't upgraded the library. The issue seems to be occuring when java native code tries to interact with the dll files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happened due to the mismatch of Java Key store File and Certificate file.

Comment: And how does OP fix it?

Comment: actually as per my application, the key will be generated when we explicitly delete it. So in case we delete , we need to reconfigure to use the new key to encrypt the password.